# Genymotion Output Sound Speed Issue

Tags: virtualbox, pulseaudio, android-emulator, genymotion

I've installed genymotion on my Ubuntu Regolith 21.04

After running a device multiple times, When I play music on Firefox, Spotify or other apps the speed is either a little bit faster or slower and the tone is not right.
(To put it in a nutshell, playback speed is not normal)

Tried changing some of the sound setting in VirtualBox but didn't help. Note that on a fresh virtual device there's no problem with it.

After creating a new virtual device I usually do the following:

1. Installing GApps (Google Play)
2. Installing Arm Translator for genymotion android 8.X
3. Installing Firefox, Spotify, Brain.fm apps

After multiple runs the sound issue appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem of pitch. That's really a pain since I want to use Genymotion to execute an app that plays backing track!
I found on an other forum a post that recommends to route all your audio through Jack:
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/audio-pitch-being-altered-when-launching-certain-applications/14574

I did not try that solution yet but I will keep you informed when I will test it.

Best,

Lucas

====== EDIT =====

Following the recommendation, I include below the essential parts of the solution provided by the above link:

**Route all audio through JACK**

Here’s basic setup…

Install those packages:

```
jack2
cadence
pulseaudio-jack
zita-ajbridge
```

Launch **Cadence** and do it’s most basic settings (to route all audio through JACK):

```
JACK Settings
[x] Auto-start JACK or LADISH at login

ALSA Audio
Alsa -> PulseAudio -> JACK (plugin)

PulseAudio
[ ] Auto-start at login

Engine
[x] Realtime

Driver
[x] ALSA
    [x] Duplex Mode !
    Device/Interface - your audio card
    Sample rate - 44100 kHz
    Buffer size - 512
    Period/Buffer - 2

System settings - Audio
[x] JACK sink (PulseAudio JACK Sink)
```

Smaller buffer size - obviously smaller will be latency, but if you just listen and don’t create music - it should be safe starting value (although outcome heavily depends on Audio hardware, usually you should aim for as small value as possible, which doesn’t introduce crackles / xruns)

Inside Cadence there is Tools - **Catia** - here you can route anything to any connection like an octopus

**Remark:** The author mentions as well a tool to perform a scan of your audio: https://github.com/raboof/realtimeconfigquickscan that can be run with (Use this script and all of it’s recommendations except maybe CPU Governors & RT Kernel):

```
perl ./realTimeConfigQuickScan.pl
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1233050)